# Easiest way to turn json_encode($data) into a data only list for a div

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am new to json_encode.

---

- A `data.php` from another function already exist and produces `json_encode($data)`
- `json_encode($data)` hold only names and sizes from `"SELECT name,size FROM lists";`
- `window.onload = function ()`
  `(function () {`
  `var a = document.getElementById('myDiv');`
  `if (a) {  //*Need list*//  }});`

---

**Is there a way to extract the `json_encode($data)` into a list form** like: NAME (SIZE) ; one name/size per row for the `window.onload` function above?

I have wasted to much time with this and would love a solution but am going to code another page list.php to run onload to fill div. Seriously want to know at this point for future knowledge.

**JSON:**

```
[{"name":"Cheese Burger","size":"100"}, 
 {"name":"miles","size":"51"},
 {"name":"Halloweens","size":"20"}]
```

Div will look like:

Cheese Burger (100)
 
milessize (51)
Halloweens (20)

---

**Normally I would code:**

```
<?php
$query  = "SELECT * FROM lists";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){?>

<li><?php echo $row['name'] . " (" . $row['size']. ") "; ?></li>

<?php } ?>
```

But I do not understand to full functionality of json and attempting to add to my knowledge base.
**So how would I attain the same result using JSON?**

Comment: you mean a list like `<li>`? please show your json

Comment: So, basically you're trying to turn that **JSON** into something like `{ "Cheese Burger: 100, "miles": 50, "Halloweens": 20 }`?  Is that correct?

Comment: @SuperScript Exactly; like this.  `<br> Cheese Burger (100)<br> miles (50)<br>Halloweens (20)` that is what it would look like if coded manually.. Sorry if Im not explaining well. But Yeah **EXACTLY RIGHT**

Comment: Please let me know if my answer is not right, I don't completely understand your question.  I want to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you well this is what you want:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var a = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("GET", "data.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
      //var data = [{"name":"Cheese Burger","size":"100"}, 
      //            {"name":"miles","size":"51"},
      //            {"name":"Halloweens","size":"20"}];
        a.innerHTML = "";       
        var html='';
        for (var i in data) {
            html +=  data[i].name + "("+ data[i].size +") <br />";
        }
    a.innerHTML=html; 
        }
    }
    hr.send(null);
}
```

it Will output in your div `<div id="mydiv" name="">`:

```
Cheese Burger(100) 
miles(51) 
Halloweens(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// var json comes from php
function convert(json){
    var obj={};
    for(var ii=0;ii<json.length;ii++){
        obj[json[ii].name]=json[ii].size;
    };
    return obj;
}
```

You would call this function with the data that came from `json_encode` on the PHP end.